# InfoPath 2010: Trouble programmatically adding rows to a repeating table/section that is nested within a repeating table

Tags: infopath, xmlwriter, infopath2010

I have a repeating table nested within a repeating table. The nested table contains 5 columns, 1 for the year, 4 for the different quarters (financial). I need to dynamically add rows to the nested table if the project lasted longer than one year. So if the project lasted 2 years, I would need to add 2 rows in the nested table and fill it with data, if it lasted 3 years, I would need to add 3, etc..

I can't seem to get the nested table to populate with any data. I am using a loop with an outside XmlWriter for the first table, and a nested XmlWriter for the nested table. Here is a code example:

```
  public void BuildHwSwForecastRow(string vendor, string description, string totalCost, XPathNavigator root)
    {
        string myNameSpace = NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my");

        using (XmlWriter writer = root.SelectSingleNode ("/my:myFields/my:HW_SW_Other_Forecast/my:Forecasts",NamespaceManager).AppendChild())
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Forecast", myNameSpace);
            writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-VendorName", myNameSpace, vendor);
            writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-Description", myNameSpace, description);
            writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-TotalCost", myNameSpace, totalCost);

            using (XmlWriter insideWriter = root.SelectSingleNode("//my:HW_SW_Other_Forecast/my:Forecasts/my:Forecast/my:Quarterly_Breakdowns", NamespaceManager).AppendChild())
            {
                insideWriter.WriteStartElement("Quarterly_Breakdown", myNameSpace);
                insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Year", myNameSpace, "2011");
                insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q1", myNameSpace, "");
                insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q2", myNameSpace, "");
                insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q3", myNameSpace, "");
                insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q4", myNameSpace, "");
                insideWriter.WriteEndElement();
                insideWriter.Close();
            }
            writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-Total", myNameSpace, "0.0");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The only difference is, second using block is outside of first using block.

```
public void BuildHwSwForecastRow(string vendor, string description, string totalCost, XPathNavigator root)
{
    string myNameSpace = NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my");

    using (XmlWriter writer = root.SelectSingleNode ("/my:myFields/my:HW_SW_Other_Forecast/my:Forecasts",NamespaceManager).AppendChild())
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Forecast", myNameSpace);
        writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-VendorName", myNameSpace, vendor);
        writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-Description", myNameSpace, description);
        writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-TotalCost", myNameSpace, totalCost);


        writer.WriteElementString("HSOF-Total", myNameSpace, "0.0");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Close();
    }

   using (XmlWriter insideWriter = root.SelectSingleNode("//my:HW_SW_Other_Forecast/my:Forecasts/my:Forecast/my:Quarterly_Breakdowns", NamespaceManager).AppendChild())
        {
            insideWriter.WriteStartElement("Quarterly_Breakdown", myNameSpace);
            insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Year", myNameSpace, "2011");
            insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q1", myNameSpace, "");
            insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q2", myNameSpace, "");
            insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q3", myNameSpace, "");
            insideWriter.WriteElementString("HSOF-Q4", myNameSpace, "");
            insideWriter.WriteEndElement();
            insideWriter.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, looking back after working with it a bit more I see the obvious mistake I made. I ended up going a different route and building the full row XML and appending it that way.